# split a string when there is a change in character without a regular expression

Tags: java, arrays

There is a way to split a string into repeating characters using a regex function but I want to do it without using it.

for example, given a string like: `"EE B"` my output will be an array of strings e.g

```
{"EE", " ", "B"}
```

my approach is:

given a string I will first find the number of unique characters in a string so I know the size of the array. Then I will change the string to an array of characters. Then I will check if the next character is the same or not. if it is the same then append them together if not begin a new string.

my code so far..

```
String myinput = "EE B";
char[] cinput = new char[myinput.length()];
cinput = myinput.toCharArray();    //turn string to array of characters
int uniquecha = myinput.length();
for (int i = 0; i < cinput.length; i++) {
    if (i != myinput.indexOf(cinput[i])) {
        uniquecha--;
}   //this should give me the number of unique characters


String[] returninput = new String[uniquecha];
Arrays.fill(returninput, "");
for (int i = 0; i < uniquecha; i++) {
    returninput[i] = "" + myinput.charAt(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < myinput.length - 1; j++) {
        if (myinput.charAt(j) == myinput.charAt(j + 1)) {
            returninput[j] += myinput.charAt(j + 1);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
} return returninput;
```

but there is something wrong with the second part as I cant figure out why it is not beginning a new string when the character changes.

Comment: Have you done any debugging to try and isolate the "something"?

Comment: returninput[0] = "" + myinput.charAt(i)  will be "E". then checks the next char it becomes "EE". when it gets to the whitespace it will break from the for loop. myinput.charAt(i) becomes myinput.charAt(1) which is "E" so the whitespace was never recorded. i just don't know how to go about updating i at this point.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Answer (score 0):

You question says that you don't want to use regex, but I see no reason for that requirement, other than this is maybe homework.  If you are open to using regex here, then there is a one line solution which splits your input string on the following pattern:

```
(?<=\S)(?=\s)|(?<=\s)(?=\S)
```

This pattern uses *lookarounds* to split whenever what precedes is a non whitespace character and what proceeds is a whitespace character, or vice-versa.

```
String input = "EE B";
String[] parts = input.split("(?<=\\S)(?=\\s)|(?<=\\s)(?=\\S)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));

[EE,  , B]
    ^^ a single space character in the middle
```

### Demo

Comment: The question clearly says *"without a regex expression"*

Comment: ^ and also [EE, , B] would not be correct in this context. the output should be an array containing 3 strings. { "EE", " ", "B" }

Comment: @Aystealthy The output _does_ in fact have an array with three strings, the middle string being empty string.  You didn't bother to check my answer.  And I think most actual developers would prefer my approach over yours.

Comment: @NicholasK Here on Stack Overflow, we're not limited to what the OP says, if what it says would not be best practice in a production software environment.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to split the characters in a string so that similar-consecutive characters stay together. If that's the case, here is how I would do it:

```
public static ArrayList<String> splitString(String str)
{
        ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
        String combo = "";

        //iterates through all the characters in the input
        for(char c: str.toCharArray()) {
            //check if the current char is equal to the last added char
            if(combo.length() > 0 && c != combo.charAt(combo.length() - 1)) {
                output.add(combo);    
                combo = "";
            }

            combo += c;
        }
        output.add(combo); //adds the last character

        return output;
}
```

Note that instead of using an array (has a fixed size) to store the output, I used an `ArrayList`, which has a variable size. Also, instead of checking the next character for equality with the current one, I preferred to use the last character for that. The variable `combo` is used to temporarily store the characters before they go to `output`.

Now, here is one way to print the result following your guidelines:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String input = "EEEE  BCD DdA";
    ArrayList<String> output = splitString(input);

    System.out.print("[");
    for(int i = 0; i < output.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print("\"" + output.get(i) + "\"");

        if(i != output.size()-1) 
            System.out.print(", ");
    }
    System.out.println("]");
}
```

The output when running the above code will be:

> ["EEEE", "  ", "B", "C", "D", " ", "D", "d", "A"]